# Implement View more/less using only CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

```
    <div className={classes.chipDiv}>
       {this.state.list.map(
                (item) => {
      return (
              <div className={classes.chip}>
              <Chip>
               {item}
              </Chip>
              </div>
           )})
     </div>


.chipDiv {
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

I have given flex-wrap to display the chips. I would like to have a view more/view less button if the chips exceed two lines. How to achieve this using only css?

Comment: please add workink code with css in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

```
.chipDiv {
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  display:flex;
  max-height:28px;/*Use According to need of your font-size*/
  overflow:hidden;
}
.chipDiv.viewMore{
   max-height:none;
}
```

In the above example, you can toggle your class `viewMore` according to your need. Or you can use hover state of your `chipDiv` for not using any javascript.

```
.chipDiv:hover{
   max-height:none;
 }
```